# how to update pandas column multiple values based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

so I am creating a dummy data for a project, and I have a million row of this table:

[image: Reason]

you can see the sub-reason column contains NaN values all of it cz i'm creating this data. what I want is to put a value based on the Reason column:

1. if the Reason is 'Maintenance' I want to put a random value between: ['Indoor Connection','Last Mile Connection']
2. if the Reason is 'New Connection'I want to put a random value between: ['Delayed Connection','Connection Request']
3. if the Reason is 'Billing' I want to put a random value between: ['Update Request','Change Personal Info']
4. if the Reason is Complaints I want to put a random value between: ['Wire Cut','Bad Service']

so what I did is a very basic approach:

```
for i in range(len(cop2)):
    if cop2['Reason'].loc[i][0] == 'Maintenance':
        cop2['Sub-Reason'].loc[i][0] = np.random.choice(list(subReason1))
    if cop2['Reason'].loc[i][0] == 'Connection':
        cop2['Sub-Reason'].loc[i][0] = np.random.choice(list(subReason2))
    if co2['Reason'].loc[i][0] == 'Billing':
        cop2['Sub-Reason'].loc[i][0] = np.random.choice(list(subReason3))
    if cop2['Reason'].loc[i][0] == 'Complaints':
        cop2['Sub-Reason'].loc[i][0] = np.random.choice(list(subReason4))
```

it works fine but it takes a veryyyy long time (50mins). how can I do this in a way that it doesn't take a long time but works fine?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try apply method? , it's probably faster

```
      df['Sub-Reason'] = df['Reason'].apply(
          lambda x: np.random.choice(list(subReason1)) if x=='Maintenance' 
          else (np.random.choice(list(subReason2)) if x=='Connection' 
else (np.random.choice(list(subReason3)) if x=='Billing' 
else np.random.choice(list(subReason4))) ))
```

#### Edited since OP 's column is actually a list , and using the first value

```
    df['Sub-Reason'] = df['Reason'].apply(
          lambda x: np.random.choice(list(subReason1)) if x[0]=='Maintenance' 
          else (np.random.choice(list(subReason2)) if x[0]=='Connection' 
else (np.random.choice(list(subReason3)) if x[0]=='Billing' 
else np.random.choice(list(subReason4))) ))
```

Comment: yes I tried it but you cannot use elif you can only use else if you try elif it says invalid syntax

Comment: i edited the response to avoid the syntax error

Comment: still doesn't work :/ : The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Comment: that's weird , i tested it on a sample data and worked , you're setting df['reason'] before the apply right ?

Comment: yea I copied the code exactly the same and it gave me this error

Comment: ahhah ! is the df['reason] a list not an only value ?

Comment: yes its a column inside the dataframe called Reason that contains about 4 values

Comment: would you check the edit?

Comment: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index